# Faulty compiler code generation or some memory corruption?

Tags: c++, c, code-generation

I am using a `C` library in my C++ project. This is the first time I ever encounter such an issue. I have a `struct` like this in the `C` library:

```
typedef struct {
  size_t count;
  int items[];
} items_list;
```

And then I do this:

```
   items_list* itemsList = get_item_list_lib(...);

    if(itemsList != NULL)
    {
        qDebug()<<"ItemCount: "<<itemsList->count;
        for(int i = 0; i = itemsList->count; i++)
        {
            qDebug()<<itemsList->items[i];
        }
    }
```

When I break at `if(itemsList != NULL)`, I can see that there are count is equal to `20`. The `qDebug()` also prints `ItemCount: 20`. Then once it enters the loop, no breakpoints hit anymore, no matter where I place them and it infinitely prints the value of `itemsList->items[i]`. I have never heard of such an issue before, does anyone have any idea? Happens in both debug and release modes.

Comment: typo: `i = itemsList->count;` should be `i < itemsList->count;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

logic error. try this:

```
items_list* itemsList = get_item_list_lib(...);

if(itemsList != NULL)
{
    qDebug()<<"ItemCount: "<<itemsList->count;
    for(int i = 0; i < itemsList->count; i++) // NOTE: less than, not equals
    {
        qDebug()<<itemsList->items[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: oh....how didn't I see this...

Comment: 4000 eyes are better than 2 - it's why we have code reviews and tests :)